# Nodejs Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have these 2 models:

1. Orders Models
2. Solutions model

## Orders Model

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Orders extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            Orders.hasMany(models.Payments, {
                foreignKey: {
                    name: 'order',
                    allowNull: false,
                },
                constraints: false,
                onDelete: 'cascade',
            });

            Orders.hasOne(models.Solutions, {
                foreignKey: {
                    name: 'order',
                    allowNull: false,
                },
                constraints: false,
                onDelete: 'cascade',
                as: "solution"

            });
        }
    }
    Orders.init(
        {
            order_no: {
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
            },
            order_date: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
            },
            
            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'Orders',
            tableName: 'Orders',
        }
    );
    return Orders;
};
```

#2. Solutions table

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Solutions extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here

            Solutions.belongsTo(models.Orders, {
                foreignKey: 'order',
                onDelete: 'cascade',
                constraints: false,
                as: "solution"
            });
        }
    }
    Solutions.init(
        {
            solutionId: {
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
            },

            content: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            additional_instruction: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: true,
            },
            date_submited: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'Solutions',
        }
    );
    return Solutions;
};
```

I am trying to get all orders where it's solution has not been submitted to the solutions table, i.e order field(Foreign key in solution table) is null.

I have tried this

```
Orders.findAndCountAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Users,
                attributes: ['username', 'email', 'uid'],
            },
            {
                model: Solutions,
                as: "solution",
                where: {
                    solutionId: {
                        [Op.notIn]: Solutions.findAll({
                            attributes: ['solutionId']
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        offset: page,
        limit,
    })
```

I was expecting to get a list of all orders where the solutions in the solution table has not been added. Am a bit new to sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter after left join, Sequelize can apply where clause directly on the join or after join.

```
Orders.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    '$orders.solution$': null,
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Solutions,
      as: "solution",
      required: false
    },
  ],
})
```

In SQL it's like :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN solutions s ON o.id = s.order AND s.order IS NULL
```

VS

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN solutions s ON o.id = s.order 
WHERE s IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a left join with a filter which excludes records from `Solutions` table if the `order` does not exit.

```
Orders.findAndCountAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Users,
                attributes: ['username', 'email', 'uid'],
            },
            {
                model: Solutions,
                as: "solution",
                required: false,                  
            },
        ],
        where: {
          '$solution.order$': null
        }, 
        offset: page,
        limit,
    })
```

Comment: am getting an error here.

errno: 1064,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order IS NULL' at line 1",
    sql: 'SELECT count(`Orders`.`order_no`) AS `count` FROM `Orders` AS `Orders` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Solutions` AS `solution` ON `Orders`.`order_no` = `solution`.`order` AND order IS NULL;',
    parameters: undefined

Comment: I've noticed that it doesn't work, it's ignoring that field when filtering. When I send a get request to that endpoint, it get's me the order with the field solution(aliased as order) being null, but in the table the field actually has a value. When I remove the filters in the include section I get the order with these field having the json representation of the related table and not null.

Comment: here is the output of your query 

```
 {
 User: {
 username: "Morph",
  email: "myemail@gmail.com",
  uid: "166a4eba-7f00-4f35-8ef8-7fad7600ae99"
},
 deadline: "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
 order_date: "2023-01-28T08:34:44.000Z",
 order_no: "02e01ecf-08bb-40d4-8697-bcffe416db32",
 owner: "166a4eba-7f00-4f35-8ef8-7fad7600ae99",
 solution: null,
 title: "Metaverse",
}
```

yet the solution is not empty.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now the filter is applied after the join is performed.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming later to this question, I have come to the conclusion that a LEFT OUTER JOIN between the two tables performs the exact same thing I was looking for. I want to give credit back to [@Shengda Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7378849/shengda-liu) and @[8bitIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9266709/8biticon) for the solution given.
In sequelize the solution would involve just adding the required field in the include statement on the target model to enforce the rule(i.e) find all rows that have an associations in the target associated table. For my case, the solution is as follows.

```
Orders.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Users,
            attributes: ['username', 'email', 'uid'],
        },
        {
            model: Solutions,
            as: "solution",
            required: true, // this is the only thing I have added
            /// and removed the where clause in the include field.  
        },
    ], 
    offset: page,
    limit,
})
```